# mathclose messes with subsript placement

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, superscripts

I defined my own command `\prt` in math mode for parentheses that has auto-scales and an optional middle `\vert` (for conditional probability). The `\mathopen` and `\mathclose` ensures that something like `P\prt{A}{B}` will display no spacing between `P` and the start of parentheses. However, this messes around with how the superscript is placed - to the right instead of on the top-right correctly.

[image]

Produced by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\prt{m o}{
    \IfNoValueTF {#2}
        {\mathopen{}\left( #1 \right)\mathclose{}}
        {\mathopen{}\left( #1 \middle| #2 \right)\mathclose{}}
}
\begin{document}

\[
\frac{1}{2} \prt{\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i y_i x_i}^2 + \frac{1}{2} \left(\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i y_i x_i\right)^2
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you use LaTeX, maybe mleftright package is for you?

Comment: well you are making an empty atom so superscripting that not the `)` so the output you show is expected

Comment: @mickep mleftright works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The superscript is to `\mathclose{}`.

You might use `mleftright` to avoid the extra spaces, but I believe there's a better way to cope with the problem.

You seem to expect that the code is `\prt{x}` or `\prt{x}[y]`, for conditional probability in the latter case. I believe that inputs such as

```
\prt{x}   \prt{x | y}
```

would be better. Also I believe that automatic sizing is not the best approach: you can clearly see that the superscript in your image is too high.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright}

\NewDocumentCommand{\prt}{s o >{\SplitArgument{1}{|}}m}{%
  \operatorname{P}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{% * means automatic sizing
    \mleft(\makeprt{\;\middle|\;}#3\mright)%
  }{% no automatic sizing
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{% no optional argument
      (\makeprt{\mid}#3)%
    }{%
      \mathopen{#2(}\makeprt{\mathrel{#2|}}#3\mathclose{#2)}%
    }%
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makeprt}{mmm}{%
  #2\IfValueT{#3}{#1#3}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\prt{A}+\prt{A|B}+\prt{A}^2 \\
\prt[\big]{A}+\prt[\big]{A|B}+\prt[\big]{A}^2 \\
\prt[\bigg]{\frac{A}{2}}+\prt[\bigg]{\frac{A}{2}|B}+\prt[\bigg]{\frac{A}{2}}^2 \\
\frac{1}{2} \prt[\bigg]{\,\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i y_i x_i}^2 \\
\frac{1}{2} \prt*{\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i y_i x_i}^{\!2}
+\frac{1}{2} \prt*{\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i y_i x_i|B}^{\!2}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

This way *you* decide whether you want automatic sizing (which you generally don't). Small spacing adjustments are necessary in several instances, look at the code.

[image]

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. One more comment: is it possible to "detect" how big the delimiters are and decide when to add `\!` for better spacing?

Comment: @Power_tile Yes, in principle, but it would cost you two extra beers at TUG in Prague.